# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.corpora'; 'gensim' is not a package

Tags: python-3.x, gensim

I'm trying to process text using gensim (specifically gensim.corpora.dictionary), but I keep getting a "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.corpora'; 'gensim' is not a package`" error. The sample code is below. I used `pip install gensim` in my command prompt in install `gensim`. I verified that numPy and sciPy were installed and up-to-date. I checked the file path of gensim and confirmed that gensim is installed on the machine. There is also a corpora folder in gensim with no obvious issues. I'm running Python 3.6.8 through the command prompt. I can call other modules, like Pandas,nltk, and NumPy, that are in the same folder location as gensim so I'm not sure why I am getting issues when I try to import gensim. I don't know how to fix this issue. Has anyone come across this issue before? I will be grateful for any help on this. Thanks.

```
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

my_documents=[  'The movie was about a spaceship and aliens',
                'I really liked the movie!',
                'Awesome action scenes, but boring characters.',
                'The movie was awful! I hate alien films.',
                'Space is cool! I liked the movie.',
                'More space films, please!']

tokenized_docs=[word_tokenize(doc.lower()) for doc in my_documents]
dic= corpora.Dictionary(tokenized_docs)
print(dic.token2id)
corpus=[dic.doc2bow(doc) for doc in tokenized_docs]
print(corpus)
```

The output generated after running `dir /s /b "python"` and `dir /s /b "pip"` in the command prompt can be found below.

C:\Users\Owner>dir /S /b "python"

C:\Users\Owner.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python

C:\Users\Owner.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.3.71659\pythonFiles\lib\python\parso\python

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\python

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code_\resources\app\extensions\python

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Python

C:\Users\Owner>dir /S /b "pip"

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\pip

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pip

C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pip

Comment: Also, I've verified that gensim is installed via the use of `pip freeze` in the command prompt. It shows `gensim == 3.8.2`

Comment: Are you sure that the `python` interpreter (environment) in which you are running your code, and getting the error, is the same one into which you pip-installed `gensim`? What happens if you run just `import gensim`? (And if that works, what does executing `gensim.__file__` show?)

Comment: Thanks for the info and time @gojomo. I'm not too sure, but you might be on to something. In the command prompt, I enter the Python environment by typing `python` then hit the enter key. Once there I get the same error message when I try to execute `import gensim`. I get a `NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined` error when I try to execute `gensim.__file__`. Does that help trouble shoot the problem? What is weird to me is that the other modules (in the same location) work when I execute them.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps, from the command-line where you typed `python`, check the output of `which python` and `which pip` - to be sure that the `pip` you're using, and the `python`, are part of the same installation/environment?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want me to execute `which python` and `which pip` in the command prompt? Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what to do.

Comment: Yes - on Unixy OSes, this will show the 'full path' to the executable you're running, which may give clues to the 'python' in use & other details.

Comment: I couldn't get `which python` or `which pip` to run in the command prompt unfortunately. I tried to use `dir /s /b "python"` and `dir /s /b "pip"`. I had two different versions of Python installed. I uninstalled the older version. Will test script again to see if that fixes issue.Output for the `dir` executions after uninstalling the old Python version has been added to the original post to avoid bogging the comments down.

Comment: Hi Mike, welcome to Stackoverflow. Some of the confusion here is because you are working in Windows and 'which' is a Linux/MacOS command. Try 'pip -V' and 'python -V' to clarify the setup. As an aside, I prefer to use virtual environments to develop in Python. Google 'python virtualenv'. It can help clarify and isolate your package setup. I got your 'from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary'  to work after I did 'import gensim'. However, when I first tried to 'pip install gensim' pip crashed on me! I needed to do 'pip install cython' first. I have Python 3.8.2 and pip 20.0.2.

Comment: I'm not sure of the interpretation of Windows `dir` output, but it certainly looks like there may be multiple pythons/environments, which couldd have contributed to your errors. Yes, per @tim's comment, a good practice is to explicitly use separate Python virtual environments, to help keep the interpreter/libraries for each project clear & distinct. Using either the Python 3 virtualenv facility, or the similar facility available through the `conda` install management tool (I prefer starting with the minimalist `miniconda` version), may help clear things up.

Comment: @Tim @gojomo, thanks for the info guys. Because multiple environments were a concern I took the following steps. I uninstalled python from my system. I also verified that there were no other versions of python on the system. I then reinstalled python 3.8.2. I created a virtual environment using venv. While in the virtual env I install modules. I then went into python and tested gensim by executing `import gensim` At first nothing happened, but on the second attempt I got the same error message. Now it consistently gives error message. Weird! Did all this in the command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I figured the issue out. My script was titled as `gensim.py` and saved in the same directory that contains the gensim scripts. I modified the title of my script and it ran fine. My guess is that the `import gensim` call was looking for a file named gensim and found my python script, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: We've all been there once, often by calling our first game pygame.py!! Your guess is right: it looked at your program not the module. Check out this very useful page in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Rookie mistake. I truly appreciate your help @Tim. Also, thanks to gojomo. It would've taken me much longer to figure this out without your guy's troubleshooting tips. Cheers!